# AngularJS: $http fire and forget (no $apply)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, exception

My custom exception-Handler is sending a logging-event over `$http` whenever an exception occurs (similar to the example in the docs https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler ).

```
angular.
  module('exceptionOverwrite', []).
  factory('$exceptionHandler', ['$log', '$http', function($log, $http) {
    return function myExceptionHandler(exception, cause) {

      $http.post('myUrl.com/logErrors', cause);
      $log.warn(exception, cause);

    };
  }]);
```

This works as desired... Except when it doesn't:

**The Problem:**

Angular uses **databinding** to bind logic from controllers to the view. However this seems to cause infinity-**loops** in this constellation:.

1. Whenever an Error occurs in a function that is bound to the view in this way, the Exception handler gets triggered (as desired).
2. the logging-event is sent via $http
3. the Server responds with some HTTP Status-Code
4. AngularJS tries to update my view with the $http-response and calls `$apply` (!!)
5. All functions bound to the view get re-evaluated
6. Unless the conditions that led to an exception in step 1 magically vanished by now, another exception is thrown and we start over in step1.

**The Question:**

How can I prevent `$http` from performing an `$apply` when the server responded? In this case a simple fire-and-forget mechanism would be more than enough, i don't care about the server-response.

Am I doing it wrong (or did i misunderstand the cause for the loop)? Since this is basically the base-example from the angular-docs for custom exceptionHandlers I am really confused why this crashes in a very common usecase.

Comment: not use $hht, use xHtmlRequest JS

Comment: So do not use Angular for the call? OR Check the http error to make sure it is not the call to the error endpoint before sending another?

Comment: @epascarello I think i don't understand what you mean by that. How would you determine if the call to the error-endpoint is desired or not? (Usually sending a request there is the desired behaviour!)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have something like:

```
<div ng-bind="service.calculate()"></div>
```

Then it will run each digest cycle and produce errors.

Remove any calls from html, this is actually good practice - functions should be adddressed only in event handlers (ng-click), in ng-if, ng-repeat, ng-show,... you should reference variables. (Also avoid filters unless they are really simple and time cheap)

Comment: Yes that is the problem that is causing the loop. However your suggestion to remove such calls from all `ng-if`, `ng-repeat`, etc. is just not possbile in my case. Also... we are talking about a global exceptionHandler here which handles every single exception in the app. I don't feel comfortable to restructure my code to make my exceptionHandler work....

Comment: This is not about exceptionHandler -- this is how it should be written to prevent bugs and bad perfomance.